# Is there a way to observe a change between Dark and Light mode on iOS using Notifications instead of the standard Delegate function?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, ios-darkmode

The standard way to check for a change between Dark and Light modes on iOS is with a view-level delegation function:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    switch self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
    case .dark:
        print("dark")
    case .light:
        print("light")
    case .unspecified:
        print("unspecified")
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

This works well, but in an app with 100's of view controllers, adding this call to every controller is a pain in the butt and is messy. What I'd like to do is observe, via NotificationCenter, changes between light and dark on the AppDelegate level. That way I can make one global theme-changing function that applies to all views.

I tried the following in AppDelegate.swift but the daytimeDidChange never gets called when changing between dark/light:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(daytimeDidChange), name: nil, object: UIScreen.main.traitCollection)

}

@objc func daytimeDidChange() {
     if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
         //Dark
         print("dark")
     }
     else {
         //Light
         print("light")
     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to set up the Notification observer properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's see what we have. I write a full answer, so if you want, skip the first paragraph.

The standard solution - as you mentioned - would be to implement this method in every (of at least in some) `UIView` / `UIViewController`:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    print("isDark: \(UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark)")
}
```

If that doesn't fit your needs, then here is another solution, which - as you want - works with notifications:

First, define a custom `NSNotification.Name` and a custom `UIWindow` implementation like this:

```
let traitCollectionDidChangeNotification = NSNotification.Name("traitCollectionDidChange")

final class MyWindow: UIWindow {
    private var userInterfaceStyle = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        let currentUserInterfaceStyle = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle
        if currentUserInterfaceStyle != userInterfaceStyle {
            userInterfaceStyle = currentUserInterfaceStyle
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: traitCollectionDidChangeNotification, object: self)
        }
    }
}
```

You can work with `String`s in the implementation if you don't want to define a global variable (although it can be outsourced to a Config file or whatever): just replace `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: traitCollectionDidChangeNotification, object: self)` with `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("traitCollectionDidChange"), object: self)`.

Then write this (if you use `AppDelegate` like me, then in the `AppDelegate`, if `SceneDelegate` then there. I use `AppDelegate`, so the example fits that, but it works with `SceneDelegate` too):

```
@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = MyWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        // instantiate your root UIViewController. Of course you can do it anyhow, as you want, don't have to use Storyboards etc.
        window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "xyz", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

From now on you receive notifications if the `userInterfaceStyle` changed. In the custom `MyWindow` implementation you can check other traits, and you don't have to check that it really changed (the `private userInterfaceStyle` property).

To get these notifications, write it literally anywhere (not only in `UIView` or `UIViewController`):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: traitCollectionDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
    print("isDark: \(UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark)")
    // Do your things...
}
```

For example if you want to use in a `UIViewController`:

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: traitCollectionDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            print("isDark: \(UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark)")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let observer = observer {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

(I know that there is a debate about the removal of the notification observers - as of [this explanation](https://oleb.net/blog/2018/01/notificationcenter-removeobserver/) I think the best to remove, but if your taste doesn't like that, just ignore the `observer`.)

I tested it on a real device (iPhone SE 2), it worked. If you have any question, feel free to ask! I hope it helps. :)